# Load entity that has been already loaded as a partial association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have encountered a strange bug related to loading an entity that is already in identity map as a partial.

Given I have following entity definition:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test")
     */
    private $related;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->created = new DateTime();
        $this->related = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addRelated(Test $related)
    {
        $this->related[] = $related;
    }
}
```

And I create two testing entities (persist them and flush the entity manager):

```
$test1 = new Test('Test 1');
$test2 = new Test('Test 2');
$test1->addRelated($test2);
```

Resulting to the following data in db:

[image]
[image]

Then I load both of them with the many-to-many association as a parial:

```
$res = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('test, partial related.{id}')
    ->from(Test::class, 'test')
    ->leftJoin('test.related', 'related')
    ->where('test.id IN (:ids)', [$id1, $id2])
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then here comes my problem:
Entity "Test 2" is loaded as `partial related.{id}` and is saved to dentity map.
Then when it should be fetched again as a full entity, it is (I suppose) loaded from the identity map, so it doesn't contain other attributes.

[image]

Is this bug, or a feature?

Comment: Looks like normal behavior of the `partial` functionality to me.

Comment: So I shouldn't join self-referencing associations as partials at all?

Comment: Partial is to be avoided in pretty much any case.

Comment: @Ocramius, what is wrong with `partial` ? I use them quote often If I don't need to retrieve all columns ?

Comment: OK, partials aren't what they seem. Thank you.

Comment: what you wanted to do I believe is ->select('test, IDENTITY(related)') instead of partial

Comment: Partial loading forces a partially loaded object into your `UnitOfWork`, therefore you will have a possibly broken object spinning in your domain.